# Implementing a function in PARI/GP

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, math-software, computer-algebra-systems

I want to define a function:

$$g(n)= \begin{cases} +1 & \text{if $n=1$},\\ +1 & \text{if $n$ is an odd indexed prime}, \\ -1 & \text{if $n$ is an even indexed prime},\\ (-1)^r & \text{if $n$ is composite and contains $r$ even indexed prime factors},\\ \end{cases}$$

in PARI/GP. By odd indexed primes I mean $p_{2k-1}$, i.e. 2, 5, 11, 17, 23... corresponding to $p_1, p_3, p_5, p_7, p_9 \ldots $, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number. Similarly even indexed primes are $p_{2k}$ i.e. 3, 7, 13, 19, 29... corresponding to $p_2, p_4, p_6, p_8, p_{10} \ldots $.

First few values of $g(n)$ corresponding to $n=1, 2, 3, 4 \ldots $ are $1, 1,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1,-1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 1 \ldots$

Can anybody tell me a simple program to implement this in PARI GP :-D

Comment: Essentially you can combine the $4$ cases to get $g(n) = (-1)^r$ where $r$ is the number of even indexed prime factors. If $n = 1$ or if $n$ is an odd indexed prime,  then there are no even indexed prime factors ($g(n) = (-1)^0 = 1$). Else if $n$ is an even indexed prime, then there is exactly $1$ even indexed prime factor ($g(n) = (-1)^1 = -1$), which is itself.

Comment: Thanks Yiyuan Lee, I didn't see it that way before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to decompose $n$ into its prime divisors, I would iterate through the prime numbers to see which one divides $n$. Code-wise, this is probably more efficient as the first method probably requires a more complex mechanism to determine the index of the prime divisors.

Code:

```
compute(n) =
{
    g = 1;
    index = 0;
    p = 0;
    while(p < n, 
        p = nextprime(p + 1); 
        index += 1;
        while(n % p == 0, n = n / p; if (index % 2 == 0, g *= -1));
    );
    printf("%d\n", g);
}

for(i = 1, 200, compute(i));
```

Output for the first 200 values of $n$:

```
1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1,
1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1,
1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1,
-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1,
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 
-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
```

Comment: This code doesn't define the function $g(n)$, does it? I mean if I write $g(100)$ I don't get $1$, but some error about "unused characters." Also, I think you should know, I'm a complete novice to programming... So how you do you define it so that $g(100)$ gives $1$.

Comment: The above defines a function equivalent to $g$. To call it, simply do compute(100). I've edited the script, do have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but should there be an "f" in "printf"? With "f" I get an error if I try compute(100)... Also I think it only fair I explain what I need $g(n)$ for: I'm trying to compute $C= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n) \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n}$... where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors. Now, when I try this sum in PARI/GP, with compute(n) in place of $g(n)$, it computes a list of $g(n)$ values and gives 0 as an answer. So how can I use $g(n)$ values to compute $C$?

Comment: @Nabigh Unfortunately I am unable to answer that. It would be good to start a new question thread that focuses on that matter.